# circuit boards, what are the numbers next to the component e.g. C156 next to SMD. capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I'm trying to buy replacement smd capacitor on a tablet circuit board. I don't know the value of it, can the number next to it on the board help. The number on the circuit board next to the one I need is C156.
Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: That's a reference designator. Look up C156 on the schematic to see what it does, or in the Bill Of Materials (BOM) to see its value. If you don't have the schematic or BOM for that circuit board, ... bad luck.

Answer (score 1):

That usually means capacitor number 156, which, unless you have the original component list is no help in defining the specification of the component.

Either you need to find the component spec on the component or get the original circuit diagram with the full list of components.

Comment: ... or remove the component and measure its value.

Comment: Or capacitor number 56 on the first page of the schematic.